# "No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories" error on running Spring Boot jar artifact

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I use `openjdk 14.0.2`, `Gradle 7.1.1` and `IntelliJ IDEA 2021.1.2`. I have a `Spring Boot` project and can run it successfully. Now I want to create an executable jar file. This is `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.3'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example.app'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
}
```

I built `main.jar` artifact like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43853983/1043882); but executing this command:

```
$ java -jar main.jar
```

causes this error:

```
ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
```

For solving the problem I tried what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49346269/1043882) by adding

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

to the `build.gradle`; but the problem is remained.

Note:

- I do not want to use `Maven` instead of `Gradle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In stead of trying to combine jar creation with intellij and gradle, just use gradle: First run `./gradlew assemble` or `./gradlew build` (if you want to also run tests and checks) the spring boot gradle plugin will create a fat jar for you which you can run with the `java -jar` command. It will be in the `./build/libs` folder.

edit: you can ofcourse also use intellij to run these gradle tasks if you prefer.

Comment: A concise and useful answer. I searched very; but your answer says what I had to do.